# Cannot return the value from a function in AJAX

Tags: ajax, vue.js, axios

Hi I cannot return the value from the function. It's returns undefined. And I don't know why. Below is the code.

```
function getData() {
    axios.get('/task')
        .then(response => {
              return response.data.tasks;
        });
}

//calls the function
getData();
```

But when i call the function getTaskData, it returns only undefined.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're dealing with Promises in this case. They do not behave like a typical function in JavaScript. I would recommend starting with some basics:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

As to your question, `getData` does not return anything, nor is there a `getTaskData` in the code you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the previews response you’re dealing with promise,
You need to wait finishing you’re Ajax request and then you deal with response, 
In your code you can do like this

```
async function getData() {
  const response = await axios.get('/task')
  return response
}
```

Call function with callback for the success and failure cases of the Promise

```
getData()
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data.tasks)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log("ERROR")
  })
```